# Docker: random Alpine packages fail to install

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, buildx, multiarch

**Context**

I have a jenkins that builds a docker image for a raspberry pi 2.
It is using buildx to emulate the ArmV7 environment during build.
This worked great until recently I got random errors during installing the apk packages.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3-alpine

# picam python module
ARG PICAMERA_RELEASE_ADDRESS="{private_repo}"
# Ardafruit python module
ARG ARDAFRUIT_RELEASE_URL="{private_repo}"

WORKDIR /tmp

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/vc/lib"

COPY ./files /app

RUN apk add --no-cache --verbose \
        raspberrypi-libs \
        bluez \
        bluez-deprecated \
        unzip \
        git \
        glib-dev \
        gobject-introspection-dev \
        cairo-dev \
        py3-cairo \
        openssl-dev \ 
        nano \
        bash \
        alpine-sdk \
    && git clone ${PICAMERA_RELEASE_ADDRESS} \
    && cd picamera \
    && su -c "python3 setup.py install" \
    && cd /tmp/ \
    && git clone ${ARDAFRUIT_RELEASE_URL} \
    && cd Adafruit_Python_DHT \
    && su -c "python3 setup.py install --force-pi2" \
    && cd /tmp/ \
    && CFLAGS="-fcommon" pip3 install \
        btlewrap==0.0.* \
        Flask==2.* \
        waitress==2.* \
        flask-cors==3.* \
        miflora==0.* \
        colorzero==2.* \
        RPi.GPIO==0.7.* \
    && cd /tmp/ \
    && chmod +x /app/main.py \
    && chmod +x /app/healthcheck.py \
    && chmod +x /app/harden.sh \
    && apk del \
        unzip \
        git \
        glib-dev \
        gobject-introspection-dev \
        cairo-dev \
        py3-cairo \
        openssl-dev \
        nano \
        bash \
        alpine-sdk \
        libc-utils \
    && rm -rf /tmp/* \
    && sh /app/harden.sh \
    && rm -f /app/harden.sh \
    && rm -f /bin/rm

# finalize
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT [ "python3" ]

CMD [ "/app/main.py" ]

HEALTHCHECK --interval=1m --timeout=10s \
  CMD python3 /app/healthcheck.py
```

**Pipeline for the build**

```
pipeline {
  environment {
    registryCredential = ''
    registryURL = ''
    scmURL = ''
    scmCredential = ''
    dockerImage = ''
    working_branch = ''
    working_dir = ''
  }
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Cloning Git') {
      steps {
        git(
            url: scmURL,
            credentialsId: scmCredential,
            branch: working_branch
        )
      }
    }
  stage('docker login') {
      steps {
        sh '$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region eu-central-1)'
      }
    }
  stage('Build Image and push it') {
    steps{
        dir(working_dir){
            sh "docker build -t $registryURL:latest --platform linux/arm/v7 --push ."
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Jenkins Output**

```
#7 [3/5] COPY ./files /app
#7 DONE 0.0s

#8 [4/5] RUN apk fix && apk add --no-cache --verbose         raspberrypi-libs       bluez         bluez-deprecated      unzip         git       glib-dev        gobject-introspection-dev       cairo-dev       py3-cairo       openssl-dev         nano         bash         alpine-sdk     && apk fix     && git clone https://{private_repo}     && cd picamera     && su -c "python3 setup.py install"     && cd /tmp/     && git clone https://{private_repo}     && cd Adafruit_Python_DHT     && su -c "python3 setup.py install --force-pi2"     && cd /tmp/     && CFLAGS="-fcommon" pip3 install         btlewrap==0.0.*         Flask==2.*         waitress==2.*         flask-cors==3.*         miflora==0.*         colorzero==2.*         RPi.GPIO==0.7.*     && cd /tmp/     && chmod +x /app/main.py     && chmod +x /app/healthcheck.py     && chmod +x /app/harden.sh     && apk del      unzip         git       glib-dev        gobject-introspection-dev       cairo-dev       py3-cairo       openssl-dev         nano         bash         alpine-sdk         libc-utils     && rm -rf /tmp/*     && sh /app/harden.sh     && rm -f /app/harden.sh     && rm -f /bin/rm
#8 0.337 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main/armv7/APKINDEX.tar.gz

#8 1.611 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community/armv7/APKINDEX.tar.gz

#8 3.302 OK: 11 MiB in 37 packages
#8 3.581 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main/armv7/APKINDEX.tar.gz

#8 4.617 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community/armv7/APKINDEX.tar.gz

#8 6.349 (1/130) Installing fakeroot (1.25.3-r3)
#8 6.382 (2/130) Installing openssl (1.1.1l-r0)
#8 6.465 (3/130) Installing libattr (2.5.1-r0)
#8 6.487 (4/130) Installing attr (2.5.1-r0)
#8 6.517 (5/130) Installing libacl (2.2.53-r0)
#8 6.540 (6/130) Installing tar (1.34-r0)
#8 6.632 (7/130) Installing pkgconf (1.7.4-r0)
#8 6.667 (8/130) Installing patch (2.7.6-r7)
#8 6.715 (9/130) Installing libstdc++ (10.3.1_git20210424-r2)
#8 6.894 (10/130) Installing lzip (1.22-r0)
#8 6.929 (11/130) Installing brotli-libs (1.0.9-r5)
#8 7.062 (12/130) Installing nghttp2-libs (1.43.0-r0)
#8 7.101 (13/130) Installing libcurl (7.79.1-r0)
#8 7.185 (14/130) Installing curl (7.79.1-r0)
#8 7.244 (15/130) Installing abuild (3.8.0_rc4-r0)
#8 7.285 Executing abuild-3.8.0_rc4-r0.pre-install
#8 7.296 ERROR: abuild-3.8.0_rc4-r0.pre-install: script exited with error 1
#8 7.321 (16/130) Installing binutils (2.35.2-r2)

#8 7.910 (17/130) Installing libmagic (5.40-r1)
#8 8.140 (18/130) Installing file (5.40-r1)
#8 8.162 (19/130) Installing libgomp (10.3.1_git20210424-r2)
#8 8.226 (20/130) Installing libatomic (10.3.1_git20210424-r2)
#8 8.249 (21/130) Installing libgphobos (10.3.1_git20210424-r2)

#8 8.735 (22/130) Installing gmp (6.2.1-r0)
#8 8.805 (23/130) Installing isl22 (0.22-r0)
#8 8.991 (24/130) Installing mpfr4 (4.1.0-r0)
#8 9.056 (25/130) Installing mpc1 (1.2.1-r0)
#8 9.093 (26/130) Installing gcc (10.3.1_git20210424-r2)

#8 13.99 (27/130) Installing musl-dev (1.2.2-r3)
#8 14.57 (28/130) Installing libc-dev (0.7.2-r3)
#8 14.59 (29/130) Installing g++ (10.3.1_git20210424-r2)

#8 18.44 (30/130) Installing make (4.3-r0)
#8 18.48 (31/130) Installing fortify-headers (1.1-r1)
#8 18.50 (32/130) Installing build-base (0.5-r2)
#8 18.51 (33/130) Installing pcre2 (10.36-r0)
#8 18.58 (34/130) Installing git (2.32.0-r0)

#8 19.63 (35/130) Installing alpine-sdk (1.0-r1)
#8 19.65 (36/130) Installing bash (5.1.4-r0)

#8 19.80 Executing bash-5.1.4-r0.post-install
#8 19.82 ERROR: bash-5.1.4-r0.post-install: script exited with error 1
#8 19.82 (37/130) Installing dbus-libs (1.12.20-r2)
#8 19.88 (38/130) Installing dbus (1.12.20-r2)
#8 19.93 Executing dbus-1.12.20-r2.pre-install
#8 19.94 ERROR: dbus-1.12.20-r2.pre-install: script exited with error 1
#8 19.96 Executing dbus-1.12.20-r2.post-install
#8 19.97 ERROR: dbus-1.12.20-r2.post-install: script exited with error 1
#8 19.97 (39/130) Installing libblkid (2.37.2-r0)
#8 20.04 (40/130) Installing libmount (2.37.2-r0)
#8 20.09 (41/130) Installing pcre (8.44-r0)
#8 20.15 (42/130) Installing glib (2.68.3-r0)
#8 20.46 (43/130) Installing json-c (0.15-r1)
#8 20.52 (44/130) Installing eudev-libs (3.2.10-r0)
#8 20.59 (45/130) Installing bluez (5.58-r2)

#8 20.91 (46/130) Installing bluez-deprecated (5.58-r2)
#8 21.06 (47/130) Installing libxau (1.0.9-r0)
#8 21.08 (48/130) Installing libmd (1.0.3-r0)
#8 21.11 (49/130) Installing libbsd (0.11.3-r0)
#8 21.14 (50/130) Installing libxdmcp (1.1.3-r0)
#8 21.16 (51/130) Installing libxcb (1.14-r2)
#8 21.27 (52/130) Installing libx11 (1.7.2-r0)
#8 21.57 (53/130) Installing libxrender (0.9.10-r3)
#8 21.59 (54/130) Installing libxext (1.3.4-r0)
#8 21.61 (55/130) Installing libpng (1.6.37-r1)
#8 21.65 (56/130) Installing freetype (2.10.4-r1)
#8 21.76 (57/130) Installing fontconfig (2.13.1-r4)
#8 21.86 (58/130) Installing pixman (0.40.0-r2)
#8 21.94 (59/130) Installing cairo (1.16.0-r3)

#8 22.10 (60/130) Installing cairo-tools (1.16.0-r3)
#8 22.20 (61/130) Installing expat-dev (2.4.1-r0)
#8 22.23 (62/130) Installing brotli-dev (1.0.9-r5)
#8 22.26 (63/130) Installing zlib-dev (1.2.11-r3)
#8 22.30 (64/130) Installing libpng-dev (1.6.37-r1)
#8 22.34 (65/130) Installing freetype-dev (2.10.4-r1)
#8 22.46 (66/130) Installing blkid (2.37.2-r0)
#8 22.50 (67/130) Installing libcap-ng (0.8.2-r0)
#8 22.52 (68/130) Installing setpriv (2.37.2-r0)
#8 22.55 (69/130) Installing libsmartcols (2.37.2-r0)
#8 22.60 (70/130) Installing findmnt (2.37.2-r0)
#8 22.64 (71/130) Installing mcookie (2.37.2-r0)
#8 22.67 (72/130) Installing hexdump (2.37.2-r0)
#8 22.70 (73/130) Installing lsblk (2.37.2-r0)
#8 22.75 (74/130) Installing libfdisk (2.37.2-r0)
#8 22.84 (75/130) Installing sfdisk (2.37.2-r0)
#8 22.87 (76/130) Installing cfdisk (2.37.2-r0)
#8 22.91 (77/130) Installing partx (2.37.2-r0)
#8 22.95 (78/130) Installing flock (2.37.2-r0)

#8 22.97 (79/130) Installing logger (2.37.2-r0)
#8 23.00 (80/130) Installing uuidgen (2.37.2-r0)
#8 23.02 (81/130) Installing libeconf (0.3.8-r1)
#8 23.04 (82/130) Installing util-linux (2.37.2-r0)
#8 23.37 (83/130) Installing util-linux-dev (2.37.2-r0)
#8 23.57 (84/130) Installing fontconfig-dev (2.13.1-r4)
#8 23.60 (85/130) Installing xorgproto (2021.4-r0)
#8 23.82 (86/130) Installing libxau-dev (1.0.9-r0)
#8 23.85 (87/130) Installing xcb-proto (1.14.1-r2)
#8 23.91 (88/130) Installing libxdmcp-dev (1.1.3-r0)
#8 23.93 (89/130) Installing libxcb-dev (1.14-r2)

#8 24.08 (90/130) Installing xtrans (1.4.0-r1)
#8 24.13 (91/130) Installing libx11-dev (1.7.2-r0)
#8 24.18 (92/130) Installing libxext-dev (1.3.4-r0)
#8 24.22 (93/130) Installing libxrender-dev (0.9.10-r3)
#8 24.25 (94/130) Installing pixman-dev (0.40.0-r2)
#8 24.27 (95/130) Installing util-macros (1.19.3-r0)
#8 24.30 (96/130) Installing xcb-util (0.4.0-r3)
#8 24.32 (97/130) Installing xcb-util-dev (0.4.0-r3)
#8 24.35 (98/130) Installing cairo-gobject (1.16.0-r3)
#8 24.38 (99/130) Installing mpdecimal (2.5.1-r1)
#8 24.42 (100/130) Installing python3 (3.9.5-r1)

#8 28.02 (101/130) Installing gettext-asprintf (0.21-r0)
#8 28.04 (102/130) Installing libunistring (0.9.10-r1)
#8 28.25 (103/130) Installing gettext-libs (0.21-r0)
#8 28.39 (104/130) Installing libxml2 (2.9.12-r1)
#8 28.57 (105/130) Installing gettext (0.21-r0)
#8 28.70 (106/130) Installing gettext-dev (0.21-r0)
#8 28.95 (107/130) Installing bzip2-dev (1.0.8-r1)
#8 28.97 (108/130) Installing libxml2-utils (2.9.12-r1)
#8 29.00 (109/130) Installing libgpg-error (1.42-r0)
#8 29.07 (110/130) Installing libgcrypt (1.9.4-r0)

#8 29.22 (111/130) Installing libxslt (1.1.34-r1)
#8 29.28 (112/130) Installing docbook-xml (4.5-r6)
#8 29.47 Executing docbook-xml-4.5-r6.post-install
#8 29.47 ERROR: docbook-xml-4.5-r6.post-install: script exited with error 1
#8 29.48 (113/130) Installing docbook-xsl (1.79.2-r2)

#8 30.38 Executing docbook-xsl-1.79.2-r2.post-install
#8 30.39 (114/130) Installing linux-headers (5.10.41-r0)
#8 30.39 ERROR: docbook-xsl-1.79.2-r2.post-install: script exited with error 1
#8 31.04 (115/130) Installing libffi-dev (3.3-r2)
#8 31.09 (116/130) Installing libpcre16 (8.44-r0)
#8 31.14 (117/130) Installing libpcre32 (8.44-r0)
#8 31.19 (118/130) Installing libpcrecpp (8.44-r0)
#8 31.22 (119/130) Installing pcre-dev (8.44-r0)

#8 31.40 (120/130) Installing glib-dev (2.68.3-r0)
#8 31.68 (121/130) Installing cairo-dev (1.16.0-r3)
#8 31.72 (122/130) Installing libltdl (2.4.6-r7)
#8 31.76 (123/130) Installing libtool (2.4.6-r7)
#8 31.99 (124/130) Installing gobject-introspection (1.68.0-r1)
#8 32.10 (125/130) Installing gobject-introspection-dev (1.68.0-r1)

#8 32.61 (126/130) Installing nano (5.7-r2)
#8 32.68 (127/130) Installing openssl-dev (1.1.1l-r0)
#8 32.84 (128/130) Installing py3-cairo (1.20.1-r0)
#8 32.87 (129/130) Installing raspberrypi-libs (0.20200813-r0)
#8 33.12 (130/130) Installing unzip (6.0-r9)
#8 33.19 Executing busybox-1.33.1-r6.trigger
#8 33.33 Executing dbus-1.12.20-r2.trigger

#8 33.48 Executing glib-2.68.3-r0.trigger
#8 33.66 No schema files found: doing nothing.
#8 33.75 5 errors; 167 packages, 603 dirs, 10399 files, 282 MiB

#8 ERROR: process "/dev/.buildkit_qemu_emulator /bin/sh -c apk fix && apk add --no-cache --verbose         raspberrypi-libs \t\tbluez         bluez-deprecated \t\tunzip         git \t\tglib-dev \t\tgobject-introspection-dev \t\tcairo-dev \t\tpy3-cairo \t\topenssl-dev \t\tnano         bash         alpine-sdk     && apk fix     && git clone ${PICAMERA_RELEASE_ADDRESS}     && cd picamera     && su -c \"python3 setup.py install\"     && cd /tmp/     && git clone ${ARDAFRUIT_RELEASE_URL}     && cd Adafruit_Python_DHT     && su -c \"python3 setup.py install --force-pi2\"     && cd /tmp/     && CFLAGS=\"-fcommon\" pip3 install         btlewrap==0.0.*         Flask==2.*         waitress==2.*         flask-cors==3.*         miflora==0.*         colorzero==2.*         RPi.GPIO==0.7.*     && cd /tmp/     && chmod +x /app/main.py     && chmod +x /app/healthcheck.py     && chmod +x /app/harden.sh     && apk del \t\tunzip         git \t\tglib-dev \t\tgobject-introspection-dev \t\tcairo-dev \t\tpy3-cairo \t\topenssl-dev \t\tnano         bash         alpine-sdk         libc-utils     && rm -rf /tmp/*     && sh /app/harden.sh     && rm -f /app/harden.sh     && rm -f /bin/rm" did not complete successfully: exit code: 5
```

As you can see there are errors while installing abuild, bash, dbus, docbook-xml and docbook-xsl but these errors are not consistent, on the run before it were only docbook-xsl (the only consistent error) in the run after, abuild and dbus installed successfully.

I am not sure what causes the problem, or how to get more information about the error.
Running the build directly on the raspberry pi works of course, so it seems the error is located somewhere in the multi-arch configuration, but I am not sure what could have changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, looks like i found my solution here:
https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/issues/12406

quote from Lyle Franklin:

> I hit this error when trying to build a cross-platform ARM64 docker
> image from a AMD64 host. However, running `docker run --rm --privileged linuxkit/binfmt:v0.8 or update-binfmts --enable` prior to running the build seems to avoid the issue. My understanding Docker
> will try to use upstream QEMU if it is installed and registered with
> the kernel, otherwise Docker will fallback to using a built-in forked
> version of QEMU. The build error above only showed up for me with the
> forked QEMU.

So I will probably add `docker run --rm --privileged linuxkit/binfmt:v0.8 && update-binfmts --enable` to my pipeline file if I encounter the error again, for now running it once solved the issue.